# How to insert a List<> into a constructor?

Tags: c#

I wanted to create a class constructor that Telefono as a parameter a string to insert into a list

The compiler I reports the error: "cannot implicitly convert to void a string"

How can I fix?

```
 public static class Telefono
    {
        public double LevelBattery { get; set; }
        public List<String> NomeTelefono { get; set; }
        public bool TelefonoON { get; set; }

        public Telefono(string telefono)
        {
            telefono = NomeTelefono.Add(telefono); //ERROR!!!!
        }

        public void ON()
        {
            Random x = new Random();
            int Batt = x.Next(100);
            LevelBatty = Batt;

            if (Levelbattery > 10)
                TelefonoON = true;
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Ricaricare subito il telefono {0}. Batteria inferiore al 10%", NomeTelefono);
                Console.ReadLine();
                TelefonoON = false;
            }

        }
```

Comment: `NomeTelefono` is null. Initialize it before using....

Comment: *That* error seems unrelated to your string insertion. Are you sure its complaining about that line? You will get a NRE runtime error though (you need to instantiate the list).

Answer (score 7):

`List<T>.Add` doesn't return anything. I think you just want to initialize your list and add the item:

```
public Telefono(string telefono)
{
    NoneTelefono = new List<string>();
    NomeTelefono.Add(telefono);
}
```

Comment: Good catch! I missed the assignment in the add.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add

```
NomeTelefono = new List<string>();
```

in the constructor